# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar el nombre del usuario en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo un programa. En mi programa hay un botón que si tú lo presionas, se te abre una nueva ventana. En esta ventana puedo escribir mi nombre y se muestra en una Label, el problema viene cuando cierro el programa y no se ha guardado el nombre. Es decir, lo que quiero es que se almacene el nombre permanentemente y al iniciar de nuevo el programa y darle al botón de perfil, se haya guardado. El error no es que no haya creado una "main window", ya que no la añadido a este código para no hacerlo más lioso.

Aquí va mi código:

```
def openNewWindowName():

new_window = Toplevel(window)
new_window.title("Perfil")
new_window.geometry("400x200")
new_window.config(bg="beige")

def name():
    label_user_name = Label(new_window, text=f"Tu nombre es: {user_name.get()}", bg="grey63")
    label_user_name.pack(side="top")

user_name_label = Label(new_window, text="Introduzca su nombre (sin apellidos): ")
user_name_label.config(bg="grey63")
user_name_label.pack(side="top")
user_name = Entry(new_window)
user_name.config(width="33")
user_name.pack(side="top")

button_user_name = Button(new_window, text="Guardar", command=name)
button_user_name.pack(side="top")
```

Comment: tkinter por si no trae como guardar datos, pero podés escribir un archivo del tipo que prefieras (txt,json,csv,etc)y alli guardar los datos y recuperarlos al iniciar el programa en caso de que los haya, sino con alguna base de datos,

Comment: Muchas gracias, no te importaría explicarme como se hace, que soy nuevo en esto :)

Comment: El como hacer lo que dijo Tincopasan dependera del formato en el que deseas guardar los datos. Por ejemplo si eliges csv y json, python incluye librerias homonimas que deberas aprender a usar. Si es base de datos, toca aprenderse, para ir iniciando, el estandar sql. Y asi con todas las posibles opciones (que son muchas como para poner en una sola respuesta.

Comment: Nota: esto es una opinion inexperta. Si buscas algo simple de entender, el funcionamiento y la sintaxis de los json se parece mucho a ciertos objetos de Python (esto es aprovechado por el modulo json para crear jsons a partir de objetos de Python), por lo que es considerablemente mas facil de entender si ya manejas bien Python. La mejor, clara y rapida forma es una base de datos, pero requiere aprenderse un "lenguaje de programacion" que en realidad es una serie de convenciones entre todos los motores de bases de datos llamada estandar sql.

Comment: Muchas gracias Dante, al final aprendí a usar sqlite3 que es una extensión para python.